# How to improve file downloader implemented

Tags: go, memory, header

I'm trying to improve the performance of a downloader that I implemented in Go.
I think I'm having issues with the memory usage because the program stuck when I try to
download a large file, like 1gb or larger. I used it to download files around
100mgb and 300mgb and all was ok. The downloader is used on a server that present the header
Accept-Ranges. Below I will show you the implementation and part of the main but first let me explain you.

## Accept-Range:bytes

In this implementation I created an http.Client to set the Header Range with the part of the file
that I'm requesting, after that i made the request. To store the response of this request I created
a temporary file, and copied the response directly to this file. The idea with this is to avoid copy
the entire response in memory. This is the implementation:

```
func DownloadPart(wg *sync.WaitGroup, tempName string, url string, part string) {
    //setting up the client to make the request
    client := http.Client{}
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)

    //setting up the requests
    request.Header.Set("Range", part)
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    checkError(err, "fatal")
    defer response.Body.Close()

    //creating the temporary file and copying
    // the response to it
    file, err := os.Create(tempName)
    checkError(err, "panic")
    defer file.Close()
    
    _, err = io.Copy(file, response.Body)
    checkError(err, "fatal")

    defer wg.Done()
}
```

This function are called in various goroutines, so I used a WaitGroup to decrease the counter when a
gorputine end to download the part of the file. After all this goroutines end I join the diferents
temporary files in a single file. This is the implementation of the join function

```
func joinFiles(name string) {
    finalFile, err := os.OpenFile(name, os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err.Error())
    }
    defer finalFile.Close()

    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(".")

    for _, f := range files {
        tempData, err := ioutil.ReadFile(f.Name())
        if err != nil {
            log.Panicln(err.Error())
        }

        if f.Name() != finalFile.Name() {
            finalFile.Write(tempData)
            os.Remove(f.Name())
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'll show you the part of the main function that use these functions

```
//start, end and rest are used to set the Range header in the requests 
//threads are the number of goroutines to used in the download
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(threads)
//initializing the goroutines
for i := 0; i < threads; i++ {
    part := fmt.Sprintf("bytes=%d-%d", start, end)
    start = end + 1
    if i == threads-1 {
        end = end + step + rest
    } else {
        end = end + step
    }
    go tools.DownloadPart(&wg, fmt.Sprintf("%d.temp", i), url, part)
}
wg.Wait()
log.Println("Joining files...")
joinFiles(name)
```

If there's a way to improve this implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest issue here is how you're stitching together the files. Calling `ioutil.ReadAll` reads the entire file's content into memory, and since you do this for all the parts you'll likely wind up with the entire file's content in memory (GC may run in the middle and free some of it.) A much better thing to do would be to use `io.Copy` on the file (after opening it with `os.Open`) to copy it into the final file. That way you won't have to store the content in memory.